# ElasticSearch query for filter a single value and a list of values at once

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make an ElasticSearch query that, gets a parameter in it's filter, sometimes this parameter is a single value and sometimes it is a list of values, I know that when it is a single value I should use "term" and when it is a list I should use "terms". but I want one query that can handle these two things, and I pass it a single value or a list and it returns the results. [all by one query], do you have any idea about how to do this?

```
query for single value:    
{'filter': {
          'and': [
                  {'term': {'first': 1}},
                  {'term': {'second': 1}},
                 ]
        },
 }
```

query for lists:

```
{'filter': {
          'and': [
                  {'terms': {'first':  [1,2,3]}},
                  {'terms': {'second': [1,2,3]}},
                 ]
        },
 }
```

but I want one query to handle both.

Answer (score 1):

Using a boolean query with a key of "should" will cause documents to be returned that match either clause.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
         "terms": {
           "first": "[1, 2]"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
           "second": "[2, 3]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For more examples check out https://github.com/rcullito/elasticSearchQueries

Answer (score 0):

You can use a terms query to handle both because you can have a list with a single value in it.

For example:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "terms" : { "field1" : ["a"] } },
                        { "terms" : { "field2" : ["b", "c"] } }
                     ]
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `bool` does not extend to the individual values in any lists.  The only way I've figured out to stretch the AND logic there is to use the `term query` for each individual value. (This may seem like it would take a lot of time at first,  but `bool` caches filters so it will just mark `True` or `False` later.